# Unexpected behavior when reading from socket

Tags: c, sockets, memory

I've wrote the following function that reads http response from the server through the socket. I had no problems reading text pages like [this page](http://www.testingmcafeesites.com) but when I try to read images:

[image: images]

the reading goes on without adding data to the buffer, even though the read returns the correct byte amount.

The function:

```
unsigned char *read_unknown_size(int fd) {
    int available_buf_size = 1000, tot_read = 0, curr_read_size;
    unsigned char *buf = calloc(available_buf_size, 1), *tmp_ptr;
    if (buf) {
        while ((curr_read_size = (int) read(fd, buf + tot_read, available_buf_size - tot_read)) != 0) {
            if (curr_read_size == -1) {
                perror("failed to read\n");
                //todo free mem
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            } else {
                tot_read += curr_read_size;
                if (tot_read >= available_buf_size) { //the buffer is full
                    available_buf_size *= 2;
                    tmp_ptr = realloc(buf, available_buf_size + tot_read);
                    if (tmp_ptr) {
                        buf = tmp_ptr;
                        memset(buf+tot_read, 0, available_buf_size - tot_read);
                    }
                    else {
                        fprintf(stderr,"realloc failed\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"calloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

The buffer after one reading of size 1000:

> 0x563a819da130 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 19:32:01 GMT\r\nServer: Apache\r\nUpgrade: h2,h2c\r\nConnection: Upgrade, close\r\nLast-Modified: Sat, 11 Jan 2014 01:32:55 GMT\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nContent-Length: 3900\r\nCache-Control: max-age=2592000\r\nExpires: Thu, 23 Dec 2021 19:32:01 GMT\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\nGIF89", <incomplete sequence \375>

A total of 379 character.

**Edit:**
After reading the data, I'm writing it to a new file, the text pages works fine but I can't open images.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Specifically how are you determining "The buffer after one reading"? If you are printing it as a string then that will not work with binary data.

Comment: How do you check the buffer? Because if you just print binary and it’s a small image there’s a NULL that stops printing at that point.

Comment: @kaylum I'll try to. As for you Q - I've checked the buf value in the debugger and printed the length using `printf("\n Total response bytes: %d\n", (int) strlen((char *) response));`. Is it wrong?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Check my answer to Kaylum

Comment: Yes, that’s wrong. It will find the first NUL in the data and that’s it. It won’t show the amount of binary data.

Comment: @Sami so how can I print the total response byte (`sizeof`?), and check if the reading is done correctly?

Comment: You need to trust the return value of `read` for the data length. Then parse the data as text where it is text and binary where it is binary. The html data is formally specified and that's what you should use to parse the content.

Comment: @kaylum, I'll do that, but there is no way to get the size myself?

Comment: `read` told you already. What do you mean by "get the size myself"? Get the size of what?

Comment: @kaylum NVM about the size, thanks you.
Do you have any idea why I can't open the images once I write the data?

Comment: I think you add `curr_read_size` to `tot_read_size` too soon.  So you copy the data to the wrong place after reallocating the buffer, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why do you think so? I'm adding it after making sure that the reading succeeded

Comment: Maybe because I don't understand your logic.  It is being handled differently from the way I'd do it.  If you're sure that my quasi-guess is wrong, that's fine; you need go no further down the path.  Have you used [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) to check what you're up to?

Comment: That `(int)` is wrong. Remove it, and use a variable of the correct type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I did - no errors nor memory leaks, but I didn't check any further. The other answers seams logic to me, I'll check the size thing tomorrow and will update the question. Thanks

Comment: Note that your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086847/unexpected-behavior-when-reading-from-socket#comment123894611_70086847) about using `printf()` with `strlen()` is completely bogus when working with binary data.  You need code to read past null bytes in the data — and `strlen()` won't, and neither will `%s` in `printf()` formats.  Also, what do you do when you get EOF (indicated by zero bytes returned by `read()`)?

Comment: `available_buf_size` is misnamed. It's the *total* buffer size, not the size of the available portion.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Re "*So you copy the data to the wrong place*", No data is being copied.

Comment: Also, how does the calling code know how big the buffer returned is?  For binary data, it is usually longer (often far longer) than the length that would be returned by `strlen()`.

Comment: Another issue with your code is that the response buffer indicates you've claimed that your implementation complies with the HTTP 1.1 specification and it doesn't. For example, it can't handle chunked encoding. You should not claim HTTP 1.1 compliance unless your code does in fact comply with the HTTP 1.1 specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that `read_unknown_size` is working, but the caller is simply printing out the buffer up until the first NUL character by using `printf("%s", buf)` or similar.<sup>[1]</sup> This is wrong for two reasons:

- If the data read contains a NUL, it will stop outputting too soon.
- If the data read doesn't contain a NUL, it will read beyond the end of the buffer.

The caller needs to output exactly the number of characters in the buffer. However, the caller has no way to determine the how many characters are in the buffer. So, in order to do anything useful with the result of the function, the function needs to return not just the buffer but the number of characters it read.

```c
// Reads until EOF is encountered.
// Returns 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and sets errno on error.
int read_rest(int fd, unsigned char **buf_ptr, size_t *total_read_ptr) {
   unsigned char *buf        = NULL;
   size_t         buf_size   = 0;
   size_t         total_read = 0;

   while (1) {
      if ( total_read == buf_size ) {
         buf_size *= 2;  // Refine this.
         unsigned char *tmp = realloc(buf, buf_size);
         if (!tmp)
            goto ERROR;

         buf = tmp;
      }

      ssize_t chunk_size = read(fd, buf + total_read, buf_size - total_read);
      if ( chunk_size < 0 )
         goto ERROR;

      if ( chunk_size == 0 ) {
         unsigned char *tmp = realloc(buf, total_read);
         if (tmp)
            buf = tmp;

         *buf_ptr        = buf;
         *total_read_ptr = total_read;
         return 0;
      }

      total_read += chunk_size;
   }

ERROR:
   free(buf);
   *buf_ptr        = NULL;
   *total_read_ptr = 0;
   return -1;
}
```

Sample caller:

```c
unsigned char *buf;
size_t         size;

if ( read_rest(in_fd, &buf, &size) == -1 ) {
   perror("Can't read from socket");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Now you have enough information to print out the contents of the buffer (e.g. using `write`).

```c
// Returns 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and sets errno on error.
int write_full(int fd, const unsigned char *buf, size_t count) {
   while ( count > 0 ) {
      ssize_t chunk_size = write(fd, buf, count);
      if ( chunk_size < 0 )
         return -1;

      buf   += chunk_size;
      count -= chunk_size;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Sample caller:

```c
if ( write_full(out_fd, buf, size) == -1 ) {
   perror("Can't write to file");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

Comments on the original code:

- Think very hard before using casts. Using `(int)read(...)` makes no sense. This is incorrect.
- It's best to include the actual error (as `perror` does) when an error occurs.
- Printing out error messages is best done outside of the I/O function.

---

1. Keep in mind that NULs are common in GIF files, and you could have one as early as the 7th character (right after `GIF89a`).

Comment: Thank you for a great detailed answer, I'll take your notes to my attention!